# How to get reference table data in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I created a Model `Account` with `accountgroup_id` which refer from `Account_group` Model. Then I call it from `route` like this

```
 Route::get('test', function () {
    return \App\Account::get()->account_group;
  });
```

**Account** Model has **belogsto** Relationship with **Account_group**

```
 class Account extends Model
 {
     protected $fillable = ['accountgroup_id', 'accountno', 'accountname','address','contactno'];

   public function account_group()
   {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Account_group');
   }
 }
```

**Account_group** Model has **hasMany** relationship with **Account**

```
class Account_group extends Model
{
   protected $fillable =['name','under'];
   public function account()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Account','accountgroup_id');
   }
 }
```

But after calling the route; I got following error.

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$account_group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue solved by calling Account with account group

```
   \App\Account::with('account_group')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the second class should be named `AccountGroup`.

And reading the error carefully will give you a clue as to what's up - `\App\Account::get()` returns a *collection* of `Account` objects, each of which will have an `AccountGroup`. So you need to choose which specific `Account` you want, then you'll be able to access the `account_group` property on it:

```
\App\Account::find(1)->account_group; // get Account with ID 1
\App\Account::first()->account_group; // get the first Account record
```